# Python Regex Compile Split string so that words appear first

Tags: python, regex, string, text, split

Say I was given a string like so

```
text = "1234 I just ? shut * the door"
```

I want to use a regex with re.compile() such that when I split the list all of the words are in front.

I.e. it should look like this.

```
text = ["I", "just", "shut", "the", "door", "1234", "?", "*"]
```

How can I use re.compile() to split the string this way?

```
import re
r = re.compile('regex to split string so that words are first').split(text)
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: split with space character and than sort them, with regex alone this can't be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you don't need `re`. Just use `str.split` with `sorted`:

```
sorted(text.split(), key=lambda x: not x.isalpha())
```

Output:

```
['I', 'just', 'shut', 'the', 'door', '1234', '?', '*']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` with `re.findall`:

```
import re
text = "1234 I just ? shut * the door"
r = sorted(text.split(), key=lambda x:(x.isalpha(), x.isdigit(), bool(re.findall('^\W+$', x))), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['I', 'just', 'shut', 'the', 'door', '1234', '?', '*']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a single regex. You can write one regex to get all words, then another regex to get everything else.

```py
import re

text = "1234 I just ? shut * the door"
r = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
words = r.findall(text)
r = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]+')
other = r.findall(text)

print(words + other) # ['I', 'just', 'shut', 'the', 'door', '1234', '?', '*']
```